# Reference a variable within an element assertion using javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

As part of my nightwatchjs test script, I have the following code

```
var dealerName = sellerWebsiteAddressQueryPage.Website.filter(val => typeof val === 'string')
```

and what I'd like to do is use this as part of an assertion, as below

```
.assert.elementPresent('li.contact-seller__action a[href*="dealerName"]');
```

But I can't seem to find the correct way to include the variable ***dealerName*** within this assertion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use string concatenation or template strings.

Comment: The same way you'd include a variable inside any other JavaScript string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
.assert.elementPresent(`li.contact-seller__action a[href*="${dealerName}"]`);
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works. Many thanks @Kamil Kiełczewski

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how your two expressions fit together, so here I assume that dealerName comes from the array you're filtering. Use `querySelector`, `Array.filter`, and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get the `dealerNames` that fulfills your condition.

```js
const sellerWebsiteAddressQueryPage = {
  Website: [1, "Alice", undefined, "Bob"]
};
const dealerNames = sellerWebsiteAddressQueryPage.Website.filter(
  val => typeof val === "string"
).filter(dealerName =>
  document.querySelector(`li.contact-seller__action a[href*="${dealerName}"]`)
);

console.log(dealerNames);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="contact-seller__action">
    <a href="site.com/dealers/Bob">Bob</a>
  </li>
<ul>
```